# Bootstrap Dropdown not working at all

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm getting this in the console.

```
function (element) {
    console.log('first');
    $(element).unbind('show.bs.dropdown');
    var $el = $(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle)
}
```

as well as (apparently unrelated)

```
    event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

the html is

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse menu_right">
<ul id="menu-submenu" class="nav navbar-nav menu_right_middle">
    <li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120 dropdown"><a title="Art" href="/" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Art <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-771" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-771"><a title="Curator" href="#link1">Curator</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your code but what I see is that you use unbind for detaching events and on for attaching. Try to access events in the same manner, eg:

bind & unbind 
OR
on & off

And, as I know you can use events on Bootstrap Dropdown only if you initialize them via javascript, but I'm not sure about that.